# Backbone: collection of models id's to an array

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is it a method in backbone that will take a collection of models and made an array of model id's or any other specified attribute in the model?

I'm able to list the model's is's in the console.log but unsure how to make an array from it

```
for (var i=0; i<collection.models.length; i++){ 
   console.log(collections.models[i].id) 
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the Underscore method [`pluck`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-pluck) for this:

```
collection.pluck("id");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/upqqL/

---

Description of `pluck` from the UnderscoreJS [docs](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck):

> A convenient version of what is perhaps the most common use-case for map: extracting a list of property values.

Comment: I cant believe I missed that, that just saved me hours of time!